# Unglobalize currency in formatCurrency

Tags: javascript, jquery, globalization

I am using [formatCurrency](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-formatcurrency/) to format currency values.

For example, I am using it to format `1000` into `$1.000,00` using:

```
$(".money").formatCurrency({ region: currencyTypeCode });
```

I want to perform calculations on these values now.  Is there any method in formatCurrency to 'unglobalize' this number from `$1.000,00` to `1000.00`?

I can write my own function but I wanted to see if I am overlooking some functionality that already existed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `toNumber()` or `asNumber()` will do the trick for you. I'm not familiar with the plugin so you'll have to play with it but for "$1.000,00" I'd start with:

```
toNumber({decimalSymbol: "," , region: currencyTypeCode });
```

https://code.google.com/p/jquery-formatcurrency/wiki/Usage

Comment: This was it, thank you.  Overlooked that I could pass region to toNumber().